# why one of eigen values of a covariance matrix is zero?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

let say you have a square matrix A, you calculate covariance of it, then calculate eigenvalues and eigen vectors. It follows that one of eigen values is equal to zero. why is it so? what does it mean in terms of interpretation of eigen vectors?

Thanks

Comment: What is the covariance of a square matrix?

Comment: Does "the covariance of $A$" mean $AA^T$?

Comment: Well, cov(X) = (X-mx)*(X-mx)'; in matlab it calculates covariance of columns; squareness is not needed at all.

Comment: to be concrete: let consider the following example (I just copied it from matlab) 
a =[17     1;     2    -2];
[v,d] =eig(cov(a))

Answer (score 1):

It is because $n$ points in $n$-dimensional space are always situated on a codimension (at least) one affine subspace. The variance in a orthogonal direction to this subspace will be zero and this variance is expressed by an eigenvalue of the covariance matrix of these $n$ points.